# After restore a site collection displays HTTP 403 forbidden

Tags: site-collection, backup, web-application, restore

- First I Took a BackUp of a Site Collection Using CentralAdmin->BackUp & Restore ->Granular Backup-> Perform a site collection backup
- Then I Restored the Backup File named `test.bak` into Another Web
  Application Using below PowerShell Command

Powershell Command :

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://sample:43883/ -path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bkup\test.bak
```

After Restoration I am trying to access that restored Web Application `http://sample:43883/`

It displays `HTTP 403 Forbidden` and `The website declined to show this webpage`

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue many times, In our cases.

The fix was, Make sure site is not locked. For some reason, SharePoint restore process put a Lock on the Site collection which causes this issue.

Could you please check this from `Central admin > application management > Configure Quota and Locks`...On this make sure your site is not locked.

Comment: Hi Waqas , I checked Your answer and My Site is not locked. Any other  Solution .?